# Compatibility of Spring, Spring Security and Spring Webflow

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow

Is there a compatibility matrix for spring, spring security and spring webflow for recent releases resp. versions running under Java 7 and JSF 2.2? Or are simply all versions > some threshold compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check on maven [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.webflow/spring-webflow) and check the compile dependencies of the versions.

for example you can see that WebFlow 2.4.4 is compatible with Spring Security 4.1.0.RELEASE and Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE which is then compatible with jsf 2.2 (through spring-web)